# Power of 1 in complex domain

Tags: complex-numbers

Recently when studying about complex numbers I encountered something peculiar.
I wanted to say that $1^n$ is still 1, in another word $1^n=(\cos0+isin(0))^n=(\cos0+i\sin0)=1$,this looks goood while for $1^n=(\cos2\pi+i\sin2\pi)^n=(\cos2n\pi+i\sin2n\pi)$ and when n is not an integer, $1^n\ne 1$
why?
Also this freaked me out totally:
$(e^{2\pi i})^{1.5}=1$
$e^{3\pi i}=-1$
as said by wolfram alpha. Why?

Comment: In the real numbers, $1$ is sufficient to uniquely identify, well, $1$.  In complex numbers it isn't; you should properly write $1+0i$ or $1e^{i \theta}$ (or the trig expansion of that).  In your question you are (effectively) treating all of the unit circle as "$1$" and this is why it's not behaving as you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working in the real numbers, saying something like $4^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2$ or $27^{\frac{1}{3}} = 3$ or even $e^\pi \approx 23.14$ is uncontroversial, since there are either one or two valid solutions and we have simple conventions.

However, in the complex numbers, you have to be more careful. There are still two solutions to $w = z^2$, but they may not be obviously a "positive" and "negative" solution. And $w = z^3$ now has *three* solutions, spaced evenly around a circle centered on the origin. Something like $w = z^\pi$ can be satisfied by an infinitude of possible values, since $w = e^{2ki}$ for any integer $k$ will work and you can show that they're all distinct.

Generally, when applying functions like this (i.e. raising to non-integer powers, but it also applies to things like logarithms) we declare a "principal argument", i.e. we only consider the solution that gives a result of $r e^{i \theta}$ where $\theta$ is in some fixed range (typically either $[0, 2 \pi)$ or $(-\pi, \pi]$ or similar), but this means that:

1. These functions have discontinuities, and
2. It is not always true that $(z^a)^b = z^{ab}$ - which is already true in the real numbers, e.g. $\left((-2)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2 \neq (-2)^1$.

Comment: Thanks bro, I've never expected to get a reply sooo soon!!! Even my math teacher hasn't responded yet. This question actually baffled every classmate I asked yesterday. But now I know a further reading on complex numbers would make a difference. 
p.s. I'm sure you mean $w=e^{2ki}$ in the 2nd paragraph

Comment: Yep, nice catch. Generally it's good to remember that complex numbers let you do things you can't do in the reals, but you also lose some things you took for granted (like total ordering of values).